# How to get bot avatar link

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

It looks silly question but I want to embed bot avatar so how to do it. Like `embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)`  I tried `bot.avatar_url` but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bot = discord.Client`, `Client` does not have `avatar_url` as an attribute. Luckily though, `Client` does have a `user` attribute you can access, which means in your case you should be able to use `bot.user.avatar_url`.

Documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.user

Answer (score 0):

Client or i should say bot, itself dont have an attribute of avatar_url cuz its just a discord client, so you need to use bot.user.avatar_url instead

```
@bot.command()
async def botavatar(ctx):
    BotAvatar = bot.user.avatar_url
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f'{bot.user.name}\'s Avatar:',
        color=discord.Colour.red())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f'{BotAvatar}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Due to recent updates to discord.py, you can get the bot's avatar url from `bot.user.avatar.url`

So, in a command

```
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx):
    await ctx.send("{}".format(self.bot.user.avatar.url))
```

Hope that helps!